# How to get response body from Express.js server using Supertest?

Tags: node.js, express, supertest

I started to write some tests for my application and I have issues to read/get response from the server. I tried many things but nothing really worked, can someone help me please ?

```
// /api/checkCreds
exports.checkCreds = async function(req, res){
//validation
if(!await User.checkCreds(req.body.username, req.body.password)){
    var result = {error: true, data: "Incorrect"}
    res.sendStatus = 401;
    return res.send(JSON.stringify(result));        
}
```

If credentials sent to the server aren't matching, return a response with "Incorrect" message back to the user.
In the test I'm trying to get data from the server to check if properties are matching the expected output.

```
    //test.js
    it("We should fail with HTTP code 401 because incorrect data is passed (username='incorrect' password='incorrect')", function(done){
       supertest(app)
       .post('/api/checkCreds')
       .send({username: 'incorrect', password: 'incorrect'})
       .expect({error: true, data: "Incorrect"})
       .expect(401, done);
   });
```

When ran, test fails because expected properties are different from the response sent by the server, which is an empty object {}.

[image: Error given by the console]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may try changing your first expect to see if you can coax supertest into showing you the actual body that it's comparing to. For example, `expect('')`

If that doesn't work, there's a version of `expect` that accepts a function. In that function, you should be able to print out what you are getting in the response body, ie. `console.log(res)`.

It may be that there's some confusion with the JSON return type-- I haven't used that directly. You could try expecting JSON.

Finally, there's a strange paragraph in the documentation that I don't think applies, but I thought I'd mention:

> One thing to note with the above statement is that superagent now sends any HTTP error (anything other than a 2XX response code) to the callback as the first argument if you do not add a status code expect (i.e. .expect(302)).

Comment: I tried using expect(' ') as my first expect but only got an error saying: "expected ' ' response body, got Unauthorized. I tried to print out the res.body in the function inside expect but the issue from my opening post persists. Finally, in the /api/checkCreds I removed JSON.stringify() but issue persisted.

Comment: Did you try an `expect(401)` before the other expects? It seems like most of the examples do this.

Comment: I tried putting expect(401) as my first expect but problem still persists.

Comment: Sorry, it's a little hard to debug from afar. You may want to start with a simple example-- perhaps directly from the supertest documentation, and make sure that works. Then, change one thing at a time, inching towards your ideal test. This should allow you to isolate the problem.

Comment: No worries, I managed to fix my problem, I will make a new post with a fix for future reference, if anyone has the same problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to fix my issue, I noticed that in the HTTP response, `Content-Type` header was set to `text/plain` and my server was returning JSON, so that probably was the thing that confused `supertest`.

I think that `res.send()` sets the header to `text/plain` by default and I had to manually set the header value to `application/json` by using `res.type('json')`. At that point I was able to read the response body without an issue.
I also learned that `res.json()` sets the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` by default, so you don't need to do it manually like with `res.send()`.

Working code:

```
// /api/checkCreds
if(!await User.checkCreds(req.body.username, req.body.password)){
    var result = {error: true, data: "Incorrect"}
    return res.status(401).json(result);       
}

//test.js
it("We should fail with HTTP code 401 because incorrect data is passed (username='incorrect' password='incorrect')", function(done){
    supertest(app)
    .post('/api/checkCreds')
    .set('Content-type', 'application/json')
    .send({username: 'incorrect', password: 'incorrect'})
    .expect(401)
    .expect(function(res){
        console.log(res.body);
    })
    .end(done); 
});
```

Feel free to correct me if I stated something that isn't quite right.